# YouTubePlayerFragment inside ReyclerView

Tags: android, fragment, android-recyclerview, android-youtube-api

I have a RecyclerView with CardViews inside it. I want each CardView to have its own YouTubePlayerFragment. Even if they can't all be active at once, I can't even seem to instantiate the YouTubePlayerFragment in any CardView but the first in the RecyclerView. When clicking the button on the card that's supposed to set up the YouTubePlayerFragment, it always sets it up on the first card, even if I've clicked the second card. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Here are the relevant parts of code:

**Holder for the fragment in CardView XML:** (using fragment directly in xml was giving binary XML exception, probably due to fragment within a fragment somewhere along the line)

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtube_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/layout_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/layout_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/layout_video_thumbnail"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/layout_video_thumbnail"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

**ViewHolder:**

```
public class VideoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

protected FrameLayout containerYouTubePlayer;
protected TextView textViewTitle;
protected ImageView imageViewThumbNail;
protected Button buttonPreview, buttonSet;
protected Context activityContext;

public VideoViewHolder(Context activityContext, View itemView) {
    super(itemView);

    this.activityContext = activityContext;
    containerYouTubePlayer = (FrameLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_holder);
    textViewTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView_title);
    imageViewThumbNail = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_video_thumbnail);
    buttonPreview = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_preview);
    buttonSet = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_set);
}
}
```

**RecyclerView Adapter:**

```
public class VideoCardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VideoViewHolder> {

private static final String TAG = "VidWall.VideoCardAdapter";
private List<VideoInfo> videoList;
private Context activityContext;

public VideoCardAdapter(Context activityContext, List<VideoInfo> videoList) {
    this.activityContext = activityContext;
    this.videoList = videoList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return videoList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoViewHolder videoViewHolder, int i) {
    final VideoInfo videoInfo = videoList.get(i);
    videoViewHolder.textViewTitle.setText(videoInfo.displayName);
    videoViewHolder.imageViewThumbNail.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(activityContext, activityContext.getResources().getIdentifier(videoInfo.fileNameThumbnail, "drawable", activityContext.getPackageName())));
    videoViewHolder.buttonPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Utils.logDebug(TAG, "buttonPreview clicked");

            // Add the YouTube fragment to view
            final YouTubePlayerFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
            ((Activity) activityContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(videoViewHolder.containerYouTubePlayer.getId(), youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
            youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(WallpapersActivity.Y_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    Utils.logDebug(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess");

                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo("xxxxxxxx");
                    youTubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                    Utils.logError(TAG, "Could not initialize YouTubePlayer");
                }
            });

            videoViewHolder.containerYouTubePlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public VideoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_wallpaper_card, viewGroup, false);

    return new VideoViewHolder(activityContext, itemView);
}

}
```

Comment: Where is the UI of the YoutubePlayerFragment ?

Comment: @MinaF.Beshay It's built into the YouTubePlayFragment as provided by the library.

Comment: OK but I get an exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x2 (unknown) for fragment YouTubePlayerFragment

Comment: @MinaF.Beshay You also have to place the YouTubePlayerFragment in your layout, did you do that?

Comment: I needed to put the fragment layout in RecyclerView which is not possible.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I figured it out. As long as you set a unique id for the YouTube FrameLayout, the activity will correctly insert the fragment on the right card! You can setId() on a View at runtime so just make sure they are somehow unique from one another.

```
   // Add the YouTube fragment to view
   wallpaperInfo.youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerFragment.newInstance();
   // Must set a unique id to the framelayout holding the fragment or else it's always added to the first item in the recyclerView (the first card)
   videoViewHolder.containerYouTubePlayer.setId(wallpaperInfo.id);
   ((Activity) activityContext).getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(videoViewHolder.containerYouTubePlayer.getId(), wallpaperInfo.youTubePlayerFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: how did you solved the issue? Can you please share some code. I tried to set the Youtube Fragment holder layouts ID unique, but still the first fragment in recyclerview loads perfectly and when i start scrolling all the views are messed up.

Comment: @Flyview Where did you place the code? I got the error "cannot find resource id", whether I place it before or after fragment manager transaction.

Comment: @DarkLeonhart I do it before the fragment transaction. I updated my answer with more code.

Comment: What is wallpaperInfo? Is that the view of the parent fragment?

Comment: @IvanLeong Sort of. It's a custom object holding some rudimentary info. However it holds the youtube playerfragment and container (view) as you can see.

Comment: But what does wallpaperInfo's Id correspond to?

Comment: @IvanLeong You are seeing highly proprietary code for the specific question. It is best to disregard the variable names.