# Youtube Video is not Displaying in RecyclerView

Tags: android, youtube, android-recyclerview, youtube-data-api

I am facing issue where youtube video is not displaying only last one is getting played and that too when I scroll the video disappears. What i wanted is every video should be displayed and every video is different.

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
.DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 10;
public  static  String key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
Context ctx;
View view;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends ViewHolder
    implements View
    .OnClickListener {
    YouTubePlayerView youTubeView;
public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    youTubeView = (YouTubePlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Adding Listener");
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
}
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    ctx=context;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                       int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.playerview_demo, parent, false);

DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
return dataObjectHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.youTubeView.initialize(key, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean b) {
        player.cueVideo(mDataset.get(position).getmText1());
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog((Activity) ctx, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("YouTube Error (%1$s)",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(ctx, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(key, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, view.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return (YouTubePlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }


});
}

public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
mDataset.remove(index);
notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
}
```

Comment: Is the desired behaviour that the video plays in place, or that it launches separate player ([example](https://youtu.be/83tXbg8qfOs?t=25s))? Would you be able to post your layout file as well please?

Comment: @PPartisan I am trying to display a list of youTube videos. so if user will click on any video. it will not open dialog or other activity. it will plan in listview or recycler where they are tag.

Comment: YouTubePlayerView does not work in a list/recycler view due to the way its implementation is. Here is what you can do: Create a YoutubeplayerActivity  and pass the video id to this activity and in the recycler view add only the thumbnails/image posters to which click event can trigger player activity.

Comment: yea it is implemented using webview. thnks @JavaGhost

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that as the `YoutubePlayer` view is too large to be added to a recyclerview. Use a `YouTubeThumbnailView` instead to display the thumbnails. When the user clicks on one of them, you can start a `YouTubePlayerFragment` or an activity with a `YouTubeplayerView` view.

**In your case this would be like this**

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter
.DataObjectHolder> {
private static String LOG_TAG = "MyRecyclerViewAdapter";
private ArrayList<DataObject> mDataset;
private static MyClickListener myClickListener;
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 10;
public  static  String key = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
Context ctx;
View view;

public static class DataObjectHolder extends ViewHolder
    implements View
    .OnClickListener {
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView ;
public DataObjectHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView ) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourId);
    itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    myClickListener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition(), v);
}
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(MyClickListener myClickListener) {
this.myClickListener = myClickListener;
}

public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<DataObject> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
    ctx=context;
}

@Override
public DataObjectHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                       int viewType) {
    view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.playerview_demo, parent, false);

DataObjectHolder dataObjectHolder = new DataObjectHolder(view);
return dataObjectHolder;
}



@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(DataObjectHolder holder, final int position) {

holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(key, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean b) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog((Activity) ctx, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            String errorMessage = String.format("YouTube Error (%1$s)",
                    errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(ctx, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(key, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, view.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return (YouTubePlayerView) view.findViewById(R.id.youtube_view);
    }


});
}

public void addItem(DataObject dataObj, int index) {
mDataset.add(index, dataObj);
notifyItemInserted(index);
}

public void deleteItem(int index) {
mDataset.remove(index);
notifyItemRemoved(index);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
return mDataset.size();
}

public interface MyClickListener {
public void onItemClick(int position, View v);
}
}
```

**Edit** 
Thanks to Irfan Raza for pointing this out. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558818/youtubeplayerfragment-inside-reyclerview) answer, it seems as if it can done

Comment: It can be done at runtime. See this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33558818/youtubeplayerfragment-inside-reyclerview

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, the items in your `RecyclerView` aren't displayed properly/fully? Some screenshots and your xml file would be helpfull.

If this is indeed the problem, check your `playerview_demo.xml` if it's `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`

If it was not set to `wrap_content` this was the issue. If not, let us know.

Comment: no there is no issue in xml. i am sharing the image how it looks.
http://postimg.org/image/iwvkzeuab/

Comment: Sorry @user1629977 , I am not using this code instead using Webview and playing Youtube videos.