# Listing YouTube Videos in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

When trying to list 10 videos of a youtube playlist in an Android activity in RecylerView. I don't get errors but I get that only last video is playable! 
the other videos are not loaded.

[image]

I use the YouTubePlayerView, as in the following code snippets,

```
public class PlaylistViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    PlaylistItem[] playlist;
    String APIKey;

    public PlaylistViewAdapter(PlaylistItem[] c, String APIKey) {

        playlist = c;
        this.APIKey = APIKey;
    }


    class PlaylistItemData extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView title;
        TextView desc;
        YouTubePlayerView videoPlayer;

        public PlaylistItemData(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            desc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            videoPlayer = (YouTubePlayerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_player_view);


        }
    }


    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.playlist_row, parent, false);

        PlaylistItemData dataObjectHolder = new PlaylistItemData(view);
        return dataObjectHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        ((PlaylistItemData) holder).videoPlayer.initialize(APIKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
         //       if (!b) {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(playlist[position].getVideoId());
       //         }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
                Log.i("onBindView", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
            }
        });
        ((PlaylistItemData) holder).title.setText(playlist[position].getTitle());
        ((PlaylistItemData) holder).desc.setText(playlist[position].getDesc());

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        return playlist.length;
    }
}
```

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36474697/1247399 so should I have to use thumbnails or webview ?

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved by using webviews instead of YouTubePlayerView